# How do I access the inputs in swipeR?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I've tried putting a sliderInput inside the `swipeR` function but I can't access it, because it's as if it were part of the image. I expected this behavior, there's nothing unusual about it.

My code:

```
# swipeR example ####
library(swipeR)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

wrapper <- swipeRwrapper(
  
  div(
    style = "border: 2px solid #008cba; padding: 8px; margin: 0 75px;",
    div(id = "div1", style="box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px;", sliderInput(inputId = "slider1", label = "Slider:", value = 15, min = 10, max = 25)),
    plotOutput("ggplot1", width = "400px", height = "300px"),
    align = "center"
  ),
  
  div(
    plotOutput("ggplot2", width = "500px", height = "400px"),
    align = "center"
  )
  
)

ui <- fluidPage(

  HTML("
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $('#div1').addClass('swiper-no-swiping');
  })
  </script>
  "),
  
  tags$script(HTML('
    document.getElementById("CAROUSEL").addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementById("div1").focus();
    });
  ')),
  
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".shiny-plot-output {border: 2px solid royalblue;}"
    ))
  ),
  
  br(),
  
  fluidRow(
    
    column(
      12,
      swipeR(
        wrapper, height = "450px", width = "80%", effect = "cube", speed = 2000,
        navigationColor = "black", rewind = TRUE, id = "CAROUSEL"
      )
    ),
    
    column(
      12,
      br(), br(), br(),
    ),
    
    column(
      3, align = "center",
      actionButton(
        "btn1", "Scatter plot", class = "btn-primary",
        onclick = "document.getElementById('CAROUSEL').swiper.slideTo(0);"
      )
    ),
    
    column(
      3, align = "center",
      actionButton(
        "btn2", "Line chart", class = "btn-primary",
        onclick = "document.getElementById('CAROUSEL').swiper.slideTo(1);"
      )
    )
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["ggplot1"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
      labs(title = "My plot title size by sliderInput") + 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = input$slider1), 
            panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "firebrick"))
  }, width = 400, height = 300)
  output[["ggplot2"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) + geom_line()
  }, width = 500, height = 400)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried to use a javascript to make the slider work, but I couldn't.

How do I use the inputs inside `swipeR`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue here is that the swipeR function captures the entire UI as if it's an image or a static slide. It's not designed to have dynamic input controls like sliders inside it, hence the challenge. The `JavaScript` solutions attempted also don't seem to have the desired effect.

To work around this and have inputs inside swipeR that can still be interacted with, we need to make some changes and utilise JavaScript. Use `JavaScript` to prevent the swipe action when the slider is clicked. We'll do this by stopping the event propagation when the slider is clicked.
Include this JavaScript in the `Shiny UI`.

Try Insert the below javascript code `script` in the `fluidPage` of your Shiny app UI to prevent swipe action on slider click:

```r
tags$script(HTML('
  $(document).on("mousedown", "#slider1", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
'))
```

Here's the full code implementation after modification is:

```r
# swipeR example ####
library(swipeR)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

wrapper <- swipeRwrapper(

  div(
    style = "border: 2px solid #008cba; padding: 8px; margin: 0 75px;",
    sliderInput(inputId = "slider1", label = "Slider:", value = 15, min = 10, max = 25),
    plotOutput("ggplot1", width = "400px", height = "300px"),
    align = "center"
  ),

  div(
    plotOutput("ggplot2", width = "500px", height = "400px"),
    align = "center"
  )

)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$script(HTML('
    $(document).on("mousedown", "#slider1", function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  ')),

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".shiny-plot-output {border: 2px solid royalblue;}"
    ))
  ),

  br(),

  fluidRow(

    column(
      12,
      swipeR(
        wrapper, height = "450px", width = "80%", effect = "cube", speed = 2000,
        navigationColor = "black", rewind = TRUE, id = "CAROUSEL"
      )
    ),

    column(
      12,
      br(), br(), br(),
    ),

    column(
      3, align = "center",
      actionButton(
        "btn1", "Scatter plot", class = "btn-primary",
        onclick = "document.getElementById('CAROUSEL').swiper.slideTo(0);"
      )
    ),

    column(
      3, align = "center",
      actionButton(
        "btn2", "Line chart", class = "btn-primary",
        onclick = "document.getElementById('CAROUSEL').swiper.slideTo(1);"
      )
    )

  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output[["ggplot1"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
      labs(title = "My plot title size by sliderInput") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = input$slider1),
            panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "firebrick"))
  }, width = 400, height = 300)

  output[["ggplot2"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) + geom_line()
  }, width = 500, height = 400)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've updated your solution, now you should be able to allow users to interact with the `slider` inside the `swipeR` element while maintaining the `swipe functionality` for the rest of the area.

==============================================

**Updated Code for Persisting issue:**

Okay, uhmmmm, then try `prevent` the `swipe event` from being triggered on the `sliderInput div` insteed. Add the class `swiper-no-swiping` directly to the `div` containing the `sliderInput` using Shiny's `tags$div` function. This is a built-in class is provided by `Swiper` which prevents swiping when an element with this class is interacted with. Then directly apply the `swiper-no-swiping class` to the `div` wrapping the `sliderInput`.

Modify the wrapper like this:

```r
wrapper <- swipeRwrapper(

  div(
    style = "border: 2px solid #008cba; padding: 8px; margin: 0 75px;",
    tags$div(class = "swiper-no-swiping", sliderInput(inputId = "slider1", label = "Slider:", value = 15, min = 10, max = 25)),
    plotOutput("ggplot1", width = "400px", height = "300px"),
    align = "center"
  ),

  div(
    plotOutput("ggplot2", width = "500px", height = "400px"),
    align = "center"
  )

)
```

You can remove the JavaScript code that adds the `swiper-no-swiping` class because you're now adding it directly.

Your updated `fluidPage`` would now look like this:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".shiny-plot-output {border: 2px solid royalblue;}"
    ))
  ),

  br(),

  fluidRow(

    column(
      12,
      swipeR(
        wrapper, height = "450px", width = "80%", effect = "cube", speed = 2000,
        navigationColor = "black", rewind = TRUE, id = "CAROUSEL"
      )
    ),

    column(
      12,
      br(), br(), br(),
    ),

    column(
      3, align = "center",
      actionButton(
        "btn1", "Scatter plot", class = "btn-primary",
        onclick = "document.getElementById('CAROUSEL').swiper.slideTo(0);"
      )
    ),

    column(
      3, align = "center",
      actionButton(
        "btn2", "Line chart", class = "btn-primary",
        onclick = "document.getElementById('CAROUSEL').swiper.slideTo(1);"
      )
    )

  )

)
```

Now, by adding the `swiper-no-swiping` class directly to the div wrapping the slider, you're informing `Swiper` to prevent swiping on this particular element. This should allow you to interact with the slider without triggering the swipe event.